My laptop refuses ssh connections until I log in from the console
My laptop refuses ssh connections until I log in from the console After I walk over to the laptop and log in from the console then it will start accepting ssh connections

It might be because of this (link is to a comment where the user answered their own question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226177/no-ssh-while-logged-off-locally#comment384577_226221)

Which distro and version of Linux are you using? Have you encrypted the home folder?
